# Java conditionals (checking for first condition within the condition)

Tags: java, conditional-statements

```
if((x == 5) || (x == 2)) {  
    [huge block of code that happens]  
    if(x == 5)  
        five();  
    if(x == 2)  
        two();  
}
```

So I'm checking for either 5 or 2. And there is a huge block of code that happens after either 5 or 2. The problem is that then I want to do different things depending on whether it is 5 or 2. I didn't want to have separate conditionals for 5 or 2 for the huge block of code (duplicating it would be unwieldy). I also didn't like the way I did it above because `x` is actually really long.

Is there a way to say something like:

```
if((x == 5) || (x == 2)) {  
    [huge block of code that happens]  
    if(first conditional was true)  
        five();  
    if(second conditional was true)  
        two();  
}
```

I can always do it the way I did above. Just curious if such an option exists.

Comment: I'd concern myself far more with [huge block of code that happens].  My first thought is "refactoring, anyone?"

Comment: It worries me that so many heavy weight answering this question has not concern about the number of if statements used in this piece of code.

Comment: i'm not an experienced coder. is this a serious problem (the number of conditionals)?

Comment: Yes absoulety check out this and I suggest subscribe to their new letter.http://www.antiifworkshop.com/ also check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298672/avoiding-multiple-if-statements-in-java and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806822/java-using-polymorphism-to-avoid-if-statements . It is not possibly to write code entirely without using if or conditional check but good OO can surely reduce it to minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way I can think of is basically to "alias" the longer boolean expressions in the `if` condition:

```
boolean expr1, expr2;

if (expr1 = (x == 5) | expr2 = (x == 2)) {  
    // huge block of code that happens
    if (expr1) five();
    if (expr2) two();
}
```

I used non short-circuiting operator to ensure expr2 gets assigned.

Comment: Soooo many years of cultural conditioning to cringe on sight... :)

Comment: If `x == 5` and `x == 2` are replaced with something much more complicated, the cute inlining could get unreadable really fast =/

Answer (score 3):

If the conditionals are big, ugly, and much less nice than `x == 5`, then just store the results in a `boolean`:

```
boolean xWasFive = x == 5;
boolean xWasTwo = !xWasFive && x == 2;
if (xWasFive || xWasTwo) {
  ...
  if (xWasFive) doA;
  else if (xWasTwo) doB;
}
```

Comment: hmm this is a pretty clean solution

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of would be to set a flag for both options.  Sort of like this:

```
boolean wasFive = x == 5;
boolean wasTwo = x == 2;

if(wasFive || wasTwo) {  
   [huge block of code that happens]  
   if(wasFive)  
       five();  
   if(wasTwo)  
       two();  
 }
```

Comment: `x == 5 ? true : false` is exactly equivalent to `x == 5`.

Comment: certainly wouldn't get through my checkstyle/findbugs configuration

Comment: @LouisWasserman - Your absolutely right and would never do that in real practice.  Thanks for the code review, I edited my answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
final boolean firstCondition = (x == 5);
final boolean secondCondition = (x == 2);

if (firstCondition || secondCondition) {
    // code
    if(firstCondition) {
        // code 
    }
    else if (secondCondition) {
        // code
    }
}
```